# Add foreign key field and choices charfield to Django user creation form

Tags: django

I would like to modify Django UserCreationForm so that it would support creating my custom user. There are required fields company and role which both should offer some kind of selection to pick the correct choice (there will be only 3 roles but there can be hundreds of companies).

I believe I need to extend UserCreationForm and modify UserAdmin. However, I have followed several different examples but so far in vain. Below is the model. How can I command Django to add the extra fields to the user creation form?

```
ROLE_CHOICES = [
    ('role1', 'Role 1'),
    ('role1', 'Role 2'),
    ('janitor', 'Janitor'),
]

class Company(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
        db_table = "company"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_company')
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=ROLE_CHOICES,
        default='janitor',
    )
    phone_number = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
        db_table = "custom_user"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. If want fields in form, you can use ModelForm and add fields. Or if you are getting any error in forms, please upload here.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I believe I need to extend UserCreationForm and modify UserAdmin. I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to extend UserCreationForm. just use this:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm): # you can name it anything
   class Meta:
      model = CustomUser
      fields = ('username', 'email', 'company',....) # add the fields here you want in form just not created. it's auto fill
```

Use this form.

If you want admin. Write this in **admins.py**

```
from .models import CustomUser
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'company'...) # add fields as you want

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Hope this help. If not, please comment.

Comment: Great, thanks, it's this simple! I'd like to go admin.py way. It almost works, however password in shown as one field which expects password in hash mode. If I could get it to ask password using the normal two fields, I would be good to go!